# jQuery PHP MSSQL json_encode not working

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, json, encode

I have seen similar questions about my issue, but don't really know how my code is not working though I have similar to the working codes I've seen. Can anyone please help me.

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Table Quick Edit</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myScript.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="margin-top:35px">
        <input id="pId" value="P.00">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and below is my php code
which I can see response in 'Response Tab' of Chrome browser.

```
<?php

include_once('dbConnection.php');
$equip = array();
echo json_encode(getProject($conn,$_POST['projId']));

function getProject ($conn,$pId){

    $tsql = "select projId, geo from dbo.proj where projId like '".$pId."'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);

    if( $stmt === false ) {
        echo "Error in executing query \n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
     do {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
               $equip[] = $row;
        }
    } while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt) );
    return $equip;
}

echo "Closing Connection... \n";
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Finally, my simple javascript to fill the '#container' element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pId').on('change', function () {

        var dataString = $('#pId').val(); //Pick-ups my input from index.html
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'php/getProjectList.php',
            dataType:'json',
            data: { 'projId': dataString },
            success: function (data) {
                 $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                    $('#container').html(v.projId);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You should echo ***only*** the JSON, remove `echo "Closing Connection... \n";` If you still have issues, check the console to find the response code and diagnose the error from there. Also note that `html()` will overwrite on successive calls in your loop. Use `append()` instead

Comment: Thanks Rory! I did but nothing changed. Still NOT proceeding to success part of ajax.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what is happening. All you've stated is that 'it's not working' which isn't really enough to offer you worthwhile help. Have you checked what the console says, and what the exact response text is in the network tab?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Yes. Have checked but nothing is prompted to my console. The ajax can send the POST request to my php file, php execute my request. But i cannot see it append to my html element.